# How do I make an object not appear grey regardless of distance?

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, graphics, rendering

My moon texture is on a plane 500m away and I would like to know if there is a way to keep displaying the texture: 
[image]
As opposed to it turning grey as pictured here:[image]
regardless of the distance it is from the camera. Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the problem. Please add more detail about import settings of the texture, the settings of the material, your camera setup and anything else which could be relevant.

Comment: Are you using fog in your scene? That's suspect #1. The next might be excessive blurring of the texture during mipmapping or selecting the wrong mipmap level, but Unity's defaults should do much better than what you've shown..

Comment: Did you try using an `Unlit` material? An object that far away shouldn't be affected by lighting.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off "Fade out Mip Map" in the texture's settings (Under Advanced)